# How can I setup an inbound action on an email incoming

Tags: email, sendgrid, mandrill, mailgun

I am developing an application, where I have a use case where I advertise a particular email id on a web site. Now, I need people to send me some information and an attachment to that email id . When I receive that email, it should trigger some action in my web application, such that I have both this document and the body of the email available to be in my web application. Then I can parse this information and take appropriate action. Let me know if it is possible to do this kind of email processing using Mandrill or Mailgun or SendGrid, and if yes, can you provide details/documention links on how this can be done.

Thanks
kabir

Answer (score 4):

All three of those services support "inbound" email parsing, which should allow you to process and react to received emails.

Essentially they'll receive and process the email on your behalf, and send you a webhook with normalized data. Docs links below.

[SendGrid Inbound Parse Webhooks](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/parse.html)

[Mailgun Inbound Routes API](http://documentation.mailgun.com/user_manual.html#receiving-forwarding-and-storing-messages)

[Mandrill Inbound Email Parsing](http://help.mandrill.com/entries/21699367-Inbound-Email-Processing-Overview)